# RewriteRule for URLs with spaces

Tags: mod-rewrite

My site's pages are in multiple languages whereby each language version shares its media (images) with the other language versions. I place all versions and the media in a single directory with the same name. E.g. pages ***mypage-en.html***, ***mypage-fr.html*** etc. will sit in directory ***mypage***.  The directory path suffices to reference a page:
h t t p : //....../mypage/
is good enough, there is no need for
h t t p : //....../mypage/mypage-en/html
A rewrite with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /$1/$2/$2-en.html
```

lets me use the shorter form. But what if the name ***mypage*** contains spaces (which some do) ?
I want
h t t p : //....../my page/
to lead to
h t t p : //....../my page/my page.html

Using

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9|\s]+)/?$ /$1/$2/$2-en.html
```

did not work.
Any hints welcome.
(please do not ask me why I want to do this, nor tell me I should not use spaces in file names)

Comment: You probably don't want the `|\s` in your matching group. A plain space `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the `|\s` in your matching group. A plain space `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` should be fine.